# java.io.FileNotFoundException in jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with a file in my jenkins workspace, I need to read a `diffFile.txt`, I'm using the global variable `WORKSPACE` like this `File fileDiff = new File(env.WORKSPACE+"/diffFile.txt")` but i get this error. I've checked and the file is there, I can read it with `cat`, but not with `File`, do you know what I can do to fix that?

Comment: What do you want to do after reading the file?

Comment: I need to read the lines in the file one by one with a for, like this `def lines = fileDiff.readLines()
            for(String line : lines){`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `File` try to use Jenkins native [readFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) step. Please check the following sample.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Dummy code to create a file with new entries 
                    sh "echo 'node1' >> nodeList.txt"
                    sh "echo 'node2' >> nodeList.txt"
                    sh "echo 'node3' >> nodeList.txt"
                    
                    // Reading the file
                    def data = readFile(file: 'nodeList.txt')
                    for(def line: data.split('\n')) {
                        echo line
                    }
                   
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```